# Why background of Google authentication is black instead transparent for FirebaseUI for Android Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-theme, firebaseui

I'm trying to use Firebase UI for Android Auth and I would like to have Google login button in my activity with an image view above and other views around. So to have this result I have thought to do the background of authentication transparent to see image behind and i am working with themes but I get black background instead transparent.

Here my code. 
Is there another way to put google login button where I want?

```
startActivityForResult(
         AuthUI.getInstance()
         .createSignInIntentBuilder()
         .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
         .setProviders(
                      AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER 
                      )
         setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent)
        .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN);
```

where Theme_Transparent:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

What I get:

```
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

What I would like to get

[image]

Comment: Since you want to show an image above the login button, have you considered using the FirebaseUI `setLogo` method?

Comment: I see this method but I have another staff to add....

Comment: Can you try disabling different attributes of your transparent theme to see which one is causing the black overlay?

Comment: I did without any affect unfortunally